# Does General Relativity require that Spacetime must be a orientable?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, topology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can spacetime be non-orientable?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/3656/can-spacetime-be-non-orientable)

Apart from the [constraints](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3656/2451) put on the topology of spacetime by QFT (Parity For example), if the global topology of a universe is that of a Mobius band and at one point there is a gravitational field pointing towards a star and a passenger travels along the band and returns to the same point. Then he will find the gravitational field pointing away from the star causing an anti-gravity effect. Does this mean that space-time must be orientable?

Answer (score 1):

I think [Can spacetime be non-orientable?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/3656) is a duplicate as qmechanic says.

One of the points not made in the answers to the previous question is that General Relativity is a local theory and does not dictate the topology of the universe at all. Whether the universe is simply connected, multiply connected or indeed non-orientable will determine what solutions are possible, but it's down to experiment to determine which solution we live in and therefore what the topology of the universe is.