# What is wormhole and how does it work?

Tags: wormholes

I want to know what are wormholes, how they function and how they are formed.
In understandable language, if possible.

Comment: Nobody knows what a wormhole is. None have ever been observed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do wormholes work?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/7817/)

Answer (score 0):

The Basic idea to this in reality and in science fiction is that you somehow manage to warp space between two distant points together. Imagine you have a piece of paper and the shortest distance between two points at the northern and southern edges of the paper is normally a straight line. Well with a wormhole you make the points touch, punch a hole in the paper, or space-time itself then step through. Then close the hole behind you. This is something that theoretically is possible due to circumstances in Einstein's theories of relativity, but it requires particles with negative energy and we have no real idea of doing that so as of now they are theoretically possible, but, realistically we're confining them to science-fiction with our current understanding and capabilities.