# Observational evidence for wormholes, or not?

Tags: general-relativity, wormholes

The Wikipedia article on [wormholes](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Wormhole) claims:

> Researchers have some observational evidence for wormholes, and the
>   equations of the theory of general relativity have valid solutions
>   that contain wormholes.

But there doesn't seem to be any details on the 'observational evidence' in the article. Also, other Physics SE questions (e.g., [How do wormholes work?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/7817/how-do-wormholes-work)) mention in passing that

> ... we have no observational evidence for 'wormholes'.
>   They are theorised solutions to general relativity equations.

So do we have some observational evidence for wormholes, or not?

Comment: There are currently no observational evidences of wormholes.

Comment: That's an "Or not.".  :-)

Comment: Agree. NOT. Wikipedia and the Wikiwand reference in the OP first line (looks like a copy of the Wikipedia article) both have the one sentence, no further mention of it, and no reference. The rest of the article is a reasonable accounting of the different ways one might get one, theoretically, but in all cases requiring some exotic matter or otherwise something not currently seen (some string option, a modification of gravity to f gravity, or otherwise negative energy conditions). The science fiction of it, though, is great fun, the 'standard' science fiction method now for interstellar travel.

Comment: Since there seems to be pretty strong consensus in these comments, I'm going to edit Wikipedia to change it.

Answer (score -1):

If [ER=EPR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ER%3DEPR) is correct (and I think it is) then entanglement is equivalent to an wormhole. And since there is experimental proof of entanglement then we could say that there's plenty of experimental proof regarding wormholes.

[Juan Maldacena, Leonard Susskind - Cool horizons for entangled black holes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1306.0533)

[Leonard Susskind - Entanglement and Complexity: Gravity and Quantum Mechanics](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9crggox5rbc&index=6&list=PL8he59NNJgleY4LbTJyQjJMpHda_E3QiY)

[Juan Maldacena - Entanglement, gravity and tensor networks Strings 2016](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iMi_QoKJYTE&index=18&list=PL8he59NNJgleY4LbTJyQjJMpHda_E3QiY)

Real world experiments http://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/sunearth/news/mag-portals.html

> "We call them X-points or electron diffusion regions," explains plasma physicist Jack Scudder of the University of Iowa. "They're places where the magnetic field of Earth connects to the magnetic field of the Sun, creating an uninterrupted path leading from our own planet to the sun's atmosphere 93 million miles away." Observations by NASA's THEMIS spacecraft and Europe's Cluster probes suggest that these magnetic portals open and close dozens of times each day. They're typically located a few tens of thousands of kilometers from Earth where the geomagnetic field meets the onrushing solar wind. Most portals are small and short-lived; others are yawning, vast, and sustained. Tons of energetic particles can flow through the openings, heating Earth's upper atmosphere, sparking geomagnetic storms, and igniting bright polar auroras.

And also:
[Magnetic wormhole Created for First Time](http://www.uab.cat/web/newsroom/news-detail/magnetic-wormhole-created-for-first-time-1345668003610.html?noticiaid=1345689132054)

And my favorite experiment which is in more QM terms :
[Intercontinental quantum liaisons between entangled electrons
in ion traps of thermoluminescent crystals - Robert Desbrandes, Daniel L. Van Gent](http://cds.cern.ch/record/998473/files/0611109.pdf)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48952/discussion-on-answer-by-mihai-b-observational-evidence-for-wormholes-or-not).

Comment: There were some citations there, important ones. Also - to whomever did it - this is not a reason to downvote something you disagree but which might be true. Thank you!