# Are topological changes to dynamic spacetime quantized? Can the Chern-Gauss-Bonnett theorem illuminate dynamics?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry, topology

I was looking at the Chern-Gauss-Bonnett theorem in dimension 4. Here we can write the Euler characteristic of a compact 4-manifold as:

$$\chi(M)=\frac{1}{32\pi^{2}}\intop_{M}\left(|\mathrm{Riem}|^{2}-4|\mathrm{Ric}|^{2}+R^{2}\right)d\mu$$

Where the Riemann and Ricci tensors and Ricci scalar are respectively considered. Naturally, I'd like to apply this to spacetime. If I do this, It makes sense to say that topology is conserved in General Relativity. In other words that the variation of $\chi(M)$ vanishes under the dynamics of spacetime.

$\delta\chi(M)=0$

In this case, we might obtain an interesting “equation of motion” for spacetime dynamics that might help relate different quantities. For example, gravitational wave energy is carried by the Weyl tensor, so we can see how this changes with changes in the Ricci scalar and such.

However, I'm not entirely sure topology IS conserved. While looking for prior research I found an [excellent paper](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/gibhaw2.pdf) (PDF) by Gibbons and Hawking that discusses topology changes to spacelike hypersurfaces, and restrictions thereof. Their conclusion is that the creation of wormholes can only be done in pairs. While I'm still digesting this paper, it appears that even then we obtain a restriction on the variation of the Euler characteristic such that it's quantized:

$$\delta\chi(M)=2n=\delta\frac{1}{32\pi^{2}}\intop_{M}\left(|\mathrm{Riem}|^{2}-4|\mathrm{Ric}|^{2}+R^{2}\right)d\mu$$

Where $n$ is an integer. In that case, we get severe limitations on the allowable structure of our curvature quantities. Can anyone weigh in here on any known utility for this??? While I haven't done the variation myself, does anyone know where this is addressed? Is my reasoning sound?

NOTE:  I'm an enormous (understatement) fan of Wheeler's Geometrodynamics and his attempts to describe particles *as* curved spacetime, so naturally these selection rules on topology change pique my interest.

Comment: Sadly I don't have the mathematical prowess to offer insight on your question, but your post makes me hopeful that you could be interested in [this rough outline](https://adamdrewherbst.pythonanywhere.com/welcome/spacetime/index?language=english&section=toc) I've been working on, in which particles are spacetime solitons.  It's how it explains the baryons that I feel is most compelling, but of course it's very half-baked, and I don't see a clear path forward to testing it.  But it does invoke Chern-Gauss-Bonnet, albeit in a very loose, qualitative way at this point...

Comment: I think there is a fundamental problem with your question:
A compact, simply connected (which is [mostly][1] assumed in GR) manifold admits a Lorentzian metric if and only if its Euler Characteristic vanishes. See for example [this][2] mathoverflow answer for a proof. Therefore a variation of the Euler characteristic does not make sense.



  [1]: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/12015/242169
  [2]: https://mathoverflow.net/a/47446

Comment: @hof_a       That is true  but there are ways around that such as those talked about by Gibbons here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1110.0611.pdf    How then is one to go about writing dynamics for topology change in spacetime if we can't take a variation? Surely there's a way?  To be honest, I'm amazed that no one has mentioned that the Gauss-Bonnett term reduces to a surface term in 4D lol!

Comment: @R.Rankin are you talking about this connected sum idea on page 5 of the linked paper? Because this would still fix your manifold (upto diffeo.) so you still can't change the Euler characteristic. My whole problem with your question is that you can't add a Chern-Gauss-Bonnet term to your action in 3+1D gravity, because this term is trivial in this case. 
You can add other topological terms (Holst, Chern-Simons like for SO(1,3), ...) to your action, see for example https://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.07764.pdf. 
What do you mean with you last sentence? For CGB the manifold has to be closed afaik.

Comment: @hof_a         Thank you, you're right of course. Since it has to vanish, I can't help but wonder if the term itself then can be written as the variation of another term? Thank you, I'm just trying to understand the dynamics of topology change in GR, for which general relativity isn't the biggest of help.

Comment: @hof_a.         I just noticed your first comment assumes simple-connectedness, which by the very nature of my question cannot be assumed at all.

Comment: @R.Rankin This is why I've refered to this (https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/12012/is-spacetime-simply-connected/12015#12015) question, which states that atleas in the context of classical general relativity spacetime is simply connected. For other topological terms see https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.07764 for example.

Comment: @hof_a     I really appreciate the comments! note that the topological censorship hypothesis you reference above, assumes an asymptotically flat spacetime, while I'm considering Compact spacetimes, for which the Chern-Gauss-Bonnett theorem holds.

Comment: The manifold needs not only compact but closed, and further this doesn't imply that it can't be asymptotically flat afaik.
I just found these two papers https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.03601 and https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.09612 which seem to address your question in more detail.

Comment: @hof_a  as per your second comment above, it must be a compact manifold without boundary, this means a closed manifold. Not sure about asymptotic flatness though. I've only been playing with $S^{3}×S^{1}$ spaces though
httpss://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_manifold